# How should I model number fields associated with timestamps in my pymongo documents?

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo

Relatively new to [py]mongo[db]...

I have a document structure, which among other things has a field structure that includes:

```
{ ...
'rssi': <int>,
'battery': <float>,
'status': <int>
'valve_status': {
    '0A000011': <int>,
    '0A000012': <int>, ...}
'pressure_in': {
    '0A000011': <int>,
    '0A000012': <int>, ...}
'pressure_out': {
    '0A000011': <int>,
    '0A000012': <int>, ...}
... }
```

So my design needs to change to accommodate saving a timestamp with each number. The timestamp is NOT the same between the different values. I'm curious what a good idiomatic way to do this would be, since I don't have a lot of experience in this field yet.

I could see 2 or 3 different approaches:

1) I could use a field naming convention to have pairs of fields. So instead of just `'rssi'`, I could have `'rssi_time'`, and just repeat the pattern for the other fields. Seems kinda cheesy, but the simplicity is kind of appealing at some level.

2) I could use a tuple for each number-time pair. So instead of `'rssi' : <int>`, it would become `'rssi' : (<int>, <timestamp>)`.

3) I could use a teeny sub document convention, so that intead of `'rssi' : <int>`, it would be come `'rssi': {'value': <int>, 'time': <timestamp>}`. This one seems the heaviest, but the most descriptive.

And maybe there's a completely different way to do it which I haven't thought of yet.

Comment: I'd suggest you do a bit of modeling using the MongoDB console and a few queries that you might want to use. If you want to query on `timestamp` for example, you'll find having it as a field of a document is far easier to deal with than if it`s a field name or in an array.

Comment: IIUC, that would steer me towards either 1 or 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not generating a lot of discussion here... I'll answer my own question. After talking with people in some other forums, I came to the conclusion that #3 was best. So far, I haven't had any issues with it.